# Can $scope.$eval be used when controller has an alias?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, eval

Currently running some tests to learn `$scope.$eval`, `$parse`, and `$interpolation`, but have encountered a head scratcher.

To conform to supposed best practices my demo controller uses the `controller as` syntax, which creates a new object literal on the `$scope` object. But the `$scope.$eval` method can no longer find the test values (e.g. `$scope.$eval('a * b')` returns `NAN`) and for good reason - values `a` and `b` are defined using the `this.a` and `this.b` technique within the controller.

I can use `$parse` of course, but before moving on I was wondering: when using the `controller as` alias technique, is `$scope.$eval` then redundant?

Plunk: [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/M2wDWsyVgtLnrEjIVcdo?p=preview)

Comment: Well, use `$scope.$eval('ctrl.a * ctrl.b')`.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. Seems like `$parse` requires less code to achieve the same, therefore `$scope.$eval` is redundant when a controller alias is present.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that you'd have to know the name of the controller used in the view, in this case 'ctrl'.

Comment: It's not a solution to any concrete problem. You haven't asked how to solve a problem. I've never had to use $eval anywhere. It's a pretty low-level method, which shouldn't be used in typical applications.